# Is the direct definition of relative permittivity the same as that obtained by electric susceptibility?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-fields, polarization

First of all, the direct definition of relative permittivity $\epsilon_r$ is obtained by the ratio of absolute permittivity $\varepsilon$ to vacuum permittivity$\varepsilon_0$:
$$
\epsilon_r = \dfrac{\varepsilon}{\varepsilon_0} \tag{1}
$$
In the polarization density, an electric susceptibility is defined:
$$
\mathbf{P} = \chi \varepsilon_0 \mathbf{E} \tag{2}
$$
where
$$
\chi = \epsilon_r - 1 \tag{3}
$$
This is $\epsilon_r$ defined from different perspectives. How to ensure that the definitions of the two are equivalent?

Comment: How do you think $\varepsilon$ is defined?

Comment: @d_b I thought eq(1) was the original definition of $\epsilon_r$, but didn't see the proof about the relationship between relative permittivity and electric susceptibility